# "Adding Printer" dialog asks for root password?

Tags: printing

I try to set up my printer under Ubuntu. So far it worked that I succeed to install the drivers. But Ubuntu says: No driver available for this model. This is the problem that Ubuntu doesn't recognize the right model, so I have to add and the choose the right driver manually. No problem I thought. But when I try to add a printer, I'm prompted to provide a root password although I didn't set up one? So i'm not able to confirm the dialog and add my printer, what's the reason?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to set a root password, if you realy want to log as root. In terminal type: "sudo passwd root" (without quotes).

Comment: Thanks, this worked so far as a workaround. It was also mentioned here.https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/system-config-printer/+bug/387970

Comment: Setting a root password is considered a bad idea, also mentioned in the bug report. The gksudo solution mentioned is better.

Answer (score 11):

If you don't want to hassle with the root passwords you can just do:
gksudo system-config-printer

Comment: This is the best workaround. I found it was because I messed with users and groups on my system and I was not a member of the lpadmin group. To add yourself to this group you can run 'sudo usermod -aG lpadmin yourusername'.

Answer (score 0):

Use your normal password - the root password is disabled in ubuntu.

Normally when su is required use sudo.

You can if needed get a root shell with sudo -i

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RootSudo

Comment: the normal password doesn't work.