# How do I share a printer?

Tags: networking, printing, share

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is needed for a networked home printer?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19694/what-is-needed-for-a-networked-home-printer)

I want to share my printer on network via ubuntu 
if I want to connect my computer to printer via USB cable.
What should I do?

Comment: [This](http://askubuntu.com/a/135257/40421) might answer your question.

Answer (score 4):

To share a printer attached to a computer on the network open the printer dialog from the menu on the cogwheel on the to panel side. Choose the printer with a right click and tick "Share" to enable sharing. Mext open *"Server -> Settings..."* from the panel menu as shown here:

[image]

This will open the following window

[image]

Select *"Show printers shared by other systems"* on the remote client, or *"Publish shared printers cnnected to to this system"* to make them visible to others on the net.

Answer (score 0):

I found [this site](http://reformedmusings.wordpress.com/2010/05/08/sharing-printers-with-ubuntu-lucid-10-04-lts-and-a-firewall/), that I think can help you in accomplishing what you are trying to do.

> Printer sharing is simple in Ubuntu. That’s because the Linux CUPS
>   (Common Unix Print System) server installed on every machine has
>   networking ability built into it. It’s ridiculously easy to set up. On
>   the computer to which the printer(s) are directly connected, just go
>   to System -> Administration -> Printing. Right click on the printers
>   that you wish to share.

<sup>Source: [reformedmusings](http://reformedmusings.wordpress.com/2010/05/08/sharing-printers-with-ubuntu-lucid-10-04-lts-and-a-firewall/)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Also you should right click on printer and click Share.
If you want to add it to Windows you must use their url. You can find url in cups web interface. you can find full tutorial about printers in ubuntu on this page: [Printers and Linux - How to find drivers, install, setup | Linux migration tutorials](http://linuxibos.blogspot.com/2012/05/seprinters-linux.html)