# Printer sharing in 2 Ubuntu computers

Tags: printing, sharing

Please help with steps involved in installing a local USB printer Epson lq 300 ) in Ubuntu and sharing it with another Ubuntu 18.  Connected in the same network.

Comment: Enable sharing on the computer it is connected to and search for a network printer on another. As simple as that.

Comment: I couldn't find an LQ300. I found a L300 and an L1300 and some others. You can search for the drivers for your printer here: http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/?OSC=LX

Comment: 1) Can you print on the PC it is attached to? 2) Have you enabled sharing on the PC it is attached to? 3) When you search from the other PC, do you see a networked printer available? Please click [edit] and advise the results. Please do not use Add Comment; instead, use [edit].

Comment: The manuals and the FAQs are here: https://epson.com/Support/wa00821 Epson doesn't "provide support" for linux but they do have instructions and drivers for linux.

Comment: Also, here is a possible duplicate: https://askubuntu.com/q/145147/167115

Answer (score 2):

On the computer with the USB printer attached (`sys1`) , point your browser at `http://localhost:631/admin` (use your login userid and password, if prompted) and look at the **Server settings:** part of the page.

Ensure that there are checks in the checkboxes labelled `Share printers connected to this system`, `Allow printing from the Internet`, and **maybe** `Allow remote administration`,`Allow users to cancel any job (not just their own)` and `Save debugging information for troubleshooting`, depending on your circumstances.

On the *other* system (`sys2`), after you've verified connectivity with `ping -c 5 sys1`, browse (to `sys2`'s `localhost`) to `http://localhost:631/admin`, and click on `Find New Printers` in the upper left part of the page.

[image: CUPS admin page]